# Delay a WaveSource in CSCore

Tags: c#, .net, cscore

I want to an audio source to be played back after a delay of 3 minutes. I tried to make kind of buffered WaveSource but the sound is played almost instantly.

That's the code I'm currently using:

```
    using (var soundIn = new WasapiCapture()
    {
        Device = GetDevice("VoiceMeeter", DataFlow.Capture)
    })
    {
        soundIn.Initialize();
        var source = new SoundInSource(soundIn)
        {
            FillWithZeros = true
        };
        soundIn.Start();

        using (var soundOut = new WasapiOut())
        {
            soundOut.Initialize(source);

            soundOut.Play();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

If anyone has a good idea how to delay the data for 3 minutes I would be very thankful. If not obvious enough I'm using the CSCore library.

Comment: Can you use async? if that's the case then `await Task.Delay(60000 * 3);` will do what you want, else just create a timer and fire the audio play after 3 minutes.

Comment: I tried to put the thread to sleep but it doesn't matter because after a certain amount of time (~35sec)  the buffer is full and it starts writing to the buffer from the start.